# How to fill in blank columns with a linear progression between known values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following row in a spreadsheet of daily figures.

[image]

I would like to add another row that would create estimates to fill in the gaps (which don't appear in a regular fashion, and can be more than one in width) so that I would be left with:

[image]

So the values added to the gaps follow a linear progression from the figure to the left, to the figure to the right (more or less - I'm not too bothered about rounding).

I could do this in a macro, but I'd love to find a formulaic way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "linear progression", you mean that the values fit to a to a linear trend, using the least squares method, and if you have O365 with the `FILTER` and `LET` functions, you can use the following:

```
=ROUND(IF(A1:P1="",TREND(FILTER(A1:P1,A1:P1<>""),LET(x,(A1:P1<>"")*SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A1:P1)),FILTER(x,x<>0)),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A1:P1))),A1:P1),0)
```

It should be possible to re-write this for earlier versions of Excel.  Basically you are using the `TREND` function to generate the least-squares linear trend, and replacing the blank cells with values from the trend line.

The results are not the same as you posted, as in your example you seem to be using a different method to determine the "linear progression"

[image]

Comment: i do have O365 and will try this later.  Thanks. I had just done mental arithmetic to divide the gaps into two or three steps.

Comment: Thanks, Ron. That does exactly what I asked for.  As a bonus it's taught me some new Excel tricks too. Every day's a school day :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are just looking for a kind of average calculation:

If there is one blank cell between A and B, then the value should be `(A+B)/2`.
If there are two blank cells between A and B, then the first value should be `A + (B-A)/3` and the second `A + 2*(B-A)/3`.
If there are three blank cells between A and B, then the first value should be `A + (B-A)/4`, the second `A + 2*(B-A)/4` and the third one `A + 3*(B-A)/4`.
...

(Note that for the first line: `(A+B)/2` is in fact the same as `A + (B-A)/2` (which shows the resemblence with the following lines).)

Comment: The problem with this is that I want a "one formula fits all" solution, as I don't know where the gaps will be appearing.